# Air handler fan relay keeps shorting out after using heat

Tags: electrical, hvac, air

Comfortmaker - FEM4X3000BL

I’ve had two fan relays go bad in the past month, each time after using heat. (This is in Florida, we only turn the heat on a few times a year.) Wiring diagram attached. Any ideas? TIA

To elaborate, heat was called for and used successfully in the morning. That evening the fan didn’t work at all in either heat or cool mode. Testing the components with a meter, I determined the fan relay was bad. As well, bypassing the relay activated the fan. I replaced the relay and used the system successfully in cool mode for a month. Then used the heat again one morning and the same thing happened.

The heat section is not represented in the schematic for some reason. There is nothing else posted on the unit itself and I don’t have the manual as the unit was installed prior to us buying the house. A search online wasn’t very helpful either. It’s a simple system with no circuit board, just the relay. I’ve attached a picture of the relay diagram.

My thoughts are the heating element is causing the relay to short, or the thermostat is somehow configured incorrectly and causing the system to switch modes too rapidly.

Thanks again for the help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to indicate what was happening when the relays went bad. Was it immediately upon turning on the heat? Was it after several hours of running? Be as specific as possible to get the best possible answer. Also, who changed the relays, was it you or did you call an HVAC professional in to do the work? If it was a pro, do they stand behind their work?

Comment: which one is the relay? all I see is a thermostat and transformer in that diagram.

Comment: Did you know that a relay or contactor is designed to short contacts together? That is all they do connect the load to the supply or a heavy duty electronic switch in reality there are only 2 things that will cause a failure in such a short time. Coil voltage many are 24v some are 120v using a 24v on a 120v system may work for a little while not long. The wrong load class contacts have to be sized for the load under sized contacts will burn open and no longer create the connection this is the opposite of shorting. Excessive load a heater element shorting and drawing high current is more likely

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for the heat kit (auxiliary/emergency heat) section of your air handler please?

Comment: Uh, a photo of the relay isn't going to tell us much of anything -- there should be a second wiring diagram posted inside your air handler near where the heaters live

Comment: There’s no other wiring diagram on the unit. I did some research though, and this is the heat kit that’s installed. Like I said, it’s a pretty simple system. https://www.aprsupply.com/2916032/Product/

Comment: Update, the fan relay shorted out again without any heat turned on, so it’s obviously not related to the heat kit. So what could be causing a relay to short over and over like this?